# Open LPLinkView url in app instead of Safari

Tags: ios, swift, url

For the newly supported [LPLinkView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation/lplinkview) in the LinkPresentation framework, is there any way to change the default action (i.e., open the url in Safari) after clicking on it？ I've read through the doc and found nothing.

My implementation:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: URL_STRING) else { return }

let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
let linkView = LPLinkView(url: url)
provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, err) in 
    guard let metadata = metadata, err == nil else { return }
    DispathQueue.main.async {
        linkView.metadata = metadata
    }
}
myStackView.insertArrangedSubview(linkView, at: 0)
```

Comment: Have you found anything since? I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: @damirstuhec Unfortunately no. May be upvote the question to get more attention D:

Comment: I have added an example for UICollectionView. Is this working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly but yes!

For example, while using it inside `UICollectionView`, if you:

1. add `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` property to `LPLinkView`
2. Use `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` delegate method
3. You can hijack the tap and use a `SFSafariViewController` you can open it in app.

Same for thing applies to `UIView` you just need to add an empty view on top of `LPLinkView` with `alpha = 0`.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks!